# In Android, what is proxy_gps_nmea_cb() used for?

Tags: android

I called

```
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, locationListener, Looper.myLooper());
```

in a thread of

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate();
```

I show logcat message as below:

```
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_location_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.152: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_sv_status_cb()
02-02 00:13:19.472: D/dalvikvm(3221): GC_CONCURRENT freed 401K, 10% free 7691K/8460K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 23ms
02-02 00:13:19.482: I/wm.cs.service(3221): count=11 location: Location[gps 37.284294,-76.723810 acc=8 et=+7m30s247ms alt=-11.550232802143439 vel=0.0 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=44]}]
02-02 00:13:20.142: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:20.142: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:20.142: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:20.142: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
02-02 00:13:20.142: D/libgps(482): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
... ...
```

Does this mean that the gps is currently actively working, consuming the battery?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding this, the GPS is, indeed, running and consuming power. I didn't manage to find the solution for now, but I'll tell you if I do (please answer your question if you found yourself, it can save me some time!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the GPS engine is working and consuming power. Also, At the top of the screen there should be a crosswire indicating the GPS is on ( and tracing you ).

Look for the program which is using the GPS and de-activate it, disallow GPS on Settings or use de locationListener to analyze the GPS Locations.